# How can I turn off "Brighten with HDR" dialog when viewing photos in Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

I'd like to turn this off:
[image]

I haven't yet found from where. Would anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short you cant. It's a proprietary app and there's nothing you could do except request for it.

But but but if you are willing to take the pain of decompiling and understanding and tweaking the code you could do so.

I knowwww how annoying those dialoges are